# class method +setLoggingEnabled: not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using Google Cloud Endpoint with iOS. I am trying to create the service object per the instructions at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios#Java_Creating_the_service_object. For the line of code `[GTMHTTPFetcher setLoggingEnabled:YES];` xCode is showing the warning

```
class method '+setLoggingEnabled:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

But when I look inside the `.h` file for `GTMHTTPFetcher` I can actually see the method as

```
#if STRIP_GTM_FETCH_LOGGING
// if logging is stripped, provide a stub for the main method
// for controlling logging
+ (void)setLoggingEnabled:(BOOL)flag;
#endif // STRIP_GTM_FETCH_LOGGING
```

and in the `.m` file it looks like this

```
#if STRIP_GTM_FETCH_LOGGING
+ (void)setLoggingEnabled:(BOOL)flag {
}
#endif // STRIP_GTM_FETCH_LOGGING
```

Also the class is generated by Google so...it should work (?)

Comment: did you define STRIP_GTM_FETCH_LOGGING?

Comment: or did the one that compiled the lib -- likely ... use atos to find out if the symbol is even in the compiled lib

Comment: I am very new to iOS.... The `.h` file that defines `STRIP_GTM_FETCH_LOGGING` is a bit different in the sense that all my other files have an `A` next to them in the `Project Navigator` and then when I try to build with `Cmd-B` I get the warning `warning: no rule to process file ‘…/GTLDefines.h' of type sourcecode.c.h for architecture i386`. I tried to solve this by going to `Build Phase` and adding it with `-fno-objc-arc`

Comment: I am facing the same problem. I am also using the GTMHTTPFetcher from the Google+ iOS SDK, so I guess they have stripped the logging? Or have you manage to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Set as follows :

```
#define STRIP_GTM_FETCH_LOGGING 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In the file that contains the following line of code:

```
[GTMHTTPFetcher setLoggingEnabled:YES];
```

Add the following importation:

```
#import "GTMHTTPFetcherLogging.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same problem.

In my case, it was because I was using the GTMHTTPFetcher from the Google+ iOS SDK:

[Adding required files to your iOS project](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_ios#Java_Adding_required_files_to_your_iOS_project) (Point 2.)

I had set the header information as described (Copied below here for simplicity):

2. If you are using the Google+ iOS SDK, set up your Xcode project as follows:

   1. In your Xcode project, go to the settings page for the target.
   2. In the `Build Settings` tab, add the following item to `Header Search Paths`:
      GOOGLE_PLUS_SDK_DIRECTORY/GoogleOpenSource.framework/Headers where
      GOOGLE_PLUS_SDK_DIRECTORY is the directory where you installed the
      Google+ iOS SDK.

(I have Google+ iOS SDK within my project so I am using: $(PROJECT_DIR)/MyProject/External/GoogleOpenSource.framework/Headers)

However to see the `setLoggingEnabled` method you will need to add `-ObjC -all_load` to `Other Linker Flags`